# Invariance of categories of sheaves (on simplicial presheaves) under (local) weak equivalence

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, simplicial-presheaves

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a Grothendieck site (secretly in my head I am thinking of Hausdorff topological spaces with open covers; if I am daring I might be thinking of the *big* etale site on complex varieties). For simplicity, I will assume that $\mathcal{C}$ has enough stalks (i.e., mono/epi-morphisms of sheaves can be detected on stalks - in the situation of open covers on a Hausdorff topological space, this is the usual notion of stalks) , and that every representable functor

$$ \underline{X} = Hom( -, X), \qquad X\in \mathcal{C} $$

is a sheaf on $\mathcal{C}$.

One extends the notion of stalk to simplicial (pre)sheaves on $\mathcal{C}$ in the evident way (levelwise), and the stalk of a simplicial presheaf is a simplicial set (which I will conflate with a topological space by taking realization).

A morphism $X \to Y$ of simplicial presheaves on $\mathcal{C}$ is a *local weak equivalence* if it induces weak equivalences on every stalk.

Now for every honest object $U \in \mathcal{C}$, I have a slice category over $U$ that inherits a topology from $\mathcal{C}$. So I can look at sheaves (of good old fashioned sets) on this site. Denote the category of these sheaves by $Sh(U)$. Assume that a morphism $f\colon U \to V$ in $\mathcal{C}$ induces a geometric morphism $f^*\colon Sh(V) \to Sh(U)$. (If it helps to put additional assumptions on $f^*$, please do so).

Now for a simplicial presheaf $X$, one can define the category of sheaves $Sh(X)$, a bit informally, as:

rules that assign to every morphism $\underline{U}\to X$, $U\in \mathcal{C}$, an object in $Sh(U)$ along with the evident compatibilities under the pullbacks from above. Formally this can be stated in terms of a right Kan extension of the Yoneda embedding of $\mathcal{C}$ into simplicial presheaves, but I hope the meaning of my informal definition above is clear.

Essentially by definition, one has pullbacks $f^*\colon Sh(Y) \to Sh(X)$ for a morphism $f\colon X\to Y$ of simplicial presheaves.

**Question**: Suppose $f\colon X\to Y$ is a local weak equivalence of simplicial (pre)sheaves. Is $f^*\colon Sh(Y) \to Sh(X)$ an equivalence of categories?

**Example -1**: If $X, Y \in \mathcal{C}$, and $\underline{X}\to \underline{Y}$ is a local weak equivalence, then $Sh(X) \cong Sh(Y)$ because a local weak equivalence here is the data of an isomorphism $X\cong Y$.

**Example 0**: Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $EG$ be the (usual) groupoid (objects: $G$, morphisms $G\times G$). Take the constant presheaf with stalk (the nerve of) $EG$. Then this presheaf is locally (in fact section/object wise) weakly equivalent to the constant presheaf with stalk $\{\ast\}$. It is "well known" that $Sh(EG) \cong Sh(\ast)$ (here, I have abused notation by writing $EG$ for the groupoid as well as the presheaf.

**Example 1**: Work on the site of Hausdorff topological spaces (perhaps assume compactly generated too) with topology given by open covers. Let $G$ be a topological group. Write $BG$ for the simplicial sheaf defined by

$$ BG(U) = B(\underline{G}(U)), $$

where, on the right hand side, for a group $\Gamma$, the (abusive once more) notation $B(\Gamma)$ denotes (the nerve of) the groupoid with single object and morphisms given by $\Gamma$. Next, define $[BG]$ by

$$ [BG](U) = nerve(\text{groupoid of principal $G$-bundles on $U$}). $$

Then the evident morphism $BG \to [BG]$ (on sections, at the groupoid level, send the single object to the trivial bundle) is a local weak equivalence.

It seems to be "well known" that $Sh(BG) \cong Sh([BG])$. (Cartesian sheaves on the "simplicial presentation" of the stack vs sheaves on the stack).

**Context:** if it is not obvious, I am a beginner trying to learn these notions. In particular, I don't have much experience with simplicial, model category, or topos theoretic arguments - willingness to learn is all I bring to the table. I have a copy of Jardine's "Local Homotopy Theory" here that is quickly looking very worn, but that's the extent of my knowledge.

For a while I had just assumed that the above question had an affirmative answer "trivially/obviously", but now I get confused every time I try to write something rigorous down.

A reference in the literature would be great. However, I am looking to *apply* these notions in a very concrete setup (my background is representation theory, not homotopy theory or even algebraic geometry). I will get very depressed if I need to wade through a thousand pages of definitions just to translate an extremely general result to the concrete statement above. So please be gentle!

Comment: I think it is true, at least for simplicial sheaves on small sites. This is because the category of simplicial sheaves and its weak equivalences can be constructed from the topos of sheaves without choosing a site, and this construction is pseudofunctorial so it respects equivalences. So you can deduce the simplicial version of the result from the ordinary version.

Comment: @ZhenLin : I think it's true too. But then I am given pause when I notice that it is "Theorems" in papers that tell you that sheaf cohomology with abelian coefficients can be computed by $Hom$ in $Ho(preSSh)$.  Like I said I thought it was "obvious" and then got tripped up when I tried to get concrete (I emphasize I am far from an expert - more like a laborer in a shop trying to find some shiny tools that will make their life easier).

Comment: For simplicial sheaves the proof is as I sketched, and the details to be filled in can be found in topos theory textbooks. For simplicial presheaves there are a lot more details to check – more than I can do in a few minutes of thinking without any paper – so I wouldn't say it's obvious (assuming it is true!).

Comment: @ZhenLin : could you give me a recommendation for a textbook that would have the details of your argument? Exposition written for beginners would be extra appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure there is a textbook that proves _this_ proposition. What I meant was that there are textbooks that cover the relevant lemmas about ordinary sheaves that you need for this proof. I'm sure it's in _Sketches of an elephant_ (but that's like saying it's in EGA...).